# 'warning C4709: comma operator within array index expression' - but no comma to be seen anywhere!

Tags: c++, visual-studio, warnings

Take this little example code:

```
struct Test{
    operator int() const{
        return 0;
    }
};

Test test(){
    return Test();
}

int main(){
    int arr[10];
    arr[test()] = 5;
}
```

Compiling under Visual Studio 2010 with `/W4` generates [said warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf1ywzyy.aspx). Interestingly, if I add but a simple default constructor, the warning suddenly vanishes. Also, it only works in that constellation. If I remove the function call or don't return a user-defined type, the warning disappears. Also, as expected, GCC doesn't produce such a warning.

So, can I take this warning with the above code as a bug in Visual Studio or is there more to it than seems? Would be very surprising though, to say the least.

---

**Edit**: Created a [bug report on Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/668639/c-c4709-when-not-even-using-comma-inside-the-array-index-expression-w4).

Comment: I can reproduce this behavior on VC++ 2008. Although to be honest I have never run across this behavior in VC++ up to now, because I always define a constructor for my classes.

Comment: @In silico: Retagged to `visual-studio` then. :)

Comment: Created a bug report on MS Connect, see the edit.

Comment: This bug is still alive in VS2013.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitely it is a bug - misleading warning.