# "Warning: Comma within array index expression" but comma is separating function arguments

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++14, compiler-warnings

MSVC reports

> warning C4709: comma operator within array index expression

on the following line:

```
intersections[img::at(rotJ, rotI)];
```

Without knowing more, is there *any* chance that this warning is valid?

Comment: No, it is misleading.

Comment: "any chance"? Sure, for example you could have `#define at x +` which would make this not actually a function call. But that doesn't seem likely to be the case.

Comment: @interjay Haha, I just *knew* someone would come up with some weird `#define`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning [C4709: comma operator within array index expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-4-c4709?view=vs-2019) is a rather buggy warning and has numerous reports all over the internet. See for e.g [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/471956/buggy-warning-c4709.html) or [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/334447/false-positive-for-c4709.html) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012068/warning-c4709-comma-operator-within-array-index-expression-but-no-comma-to) (9 years old).

So the answer is, it is misleading.

Note that if someone were to use the comma-operator within the array index:

```
int a[3] = {1, 2, 3};
cout << a[1, 2]; // outputs 3
```

Comment: Maybe interesting to know is that the use of the comma operator in the operator[] is deprecated in C++20

Comment: Good things happening ;)